# Get only the older order from transaction table for same customer

Tags: sql, conditional-statements, where-clause

I need to get only the older order from transaction table for same customer

```
SELECT * 
FROM Order_Cust
WHERE Status IN (15)
  AND to_char(Order_date, 'yyyy') = 2020
```

[image]

I need order with `order_date` to appear only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ROW_NUMBER` is one option here:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerID ORDER BY Order_date) rn
    FROM yourTable t
)

SELECT Order_Date, CustomerID, Order_Type
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

and u can try this!!

```
select * from Order_Cust
where order_date in (select max(order_date) from Order_Cust)
```